# what does this code do in openid mvc3 example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I use openid in mvc3 razor,
Please explain this code

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])" method="post" id="openid_form">
```

Comment: http://andrewblogs.com/openid-for-asp-net-mvc-a-quick-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it redirects the user to the 'Authentication' action* and passes along the current ReturnUrl query string parameter.

** , *** Example: if you called this form from the page

```
  http://localhost:56507/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=localhost%2fjumbo%20rob ,
```

it would redirect to

```
  http://localhost:56507/Home/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=localhost%2fjumbo%20rob
```

Okay, let dissect the code.

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])"  method="post" id="openid_form"
```

Its a form tag. The form tag has an action attribute. The action attribute of a form specifies where (the url) to which to send the form-data when a form is submitted. In this case, the url specified is "Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])"

Lets dissect the url. 'Authenticate' is a name of the url where it goes and is likely an action in the same controller (the post url will only really replace the thing after the last slash this code is for a relative url).

The url then has a querystring with a paremeter called ReturnUrl. The value for this parameter is the url encoded form of ReturnUrl in the current window querystring. It re-encodes the querystring to reconvert the " "s to "%20"s, etc.